# How to fix the logical error in my while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

Hello programmers of StackOverFlow, I am a teenager that studies Python, And I can't find the logical errors in one of my codes. I wish you could help with that. 
I got two logical errors.
 1. If the answer is "yes" or "no" it keeps opening the while commands while it shouldn't.
 2. Concluding from first error it never stops when the choice == "yes" or "no"..

My coding is here:

```
choice = raw_input("Do you like programming? (yes/no) : ")
while choice != "yes" or "no":
    choice = raw_input('Come on, answer with a "yes" or with a "no" ! : ') 
if choice == "yes":
    print "I like you !"
elif choice == "no":
    print "I am sorry to hear that .. "
```

, Thank you in advance !

Comment: `if` statement indentation is fine. They're intended to be outside the loop.

Comment: while choice != "yes" AND "no" ... just change 'or' to 'and' @kindall hehe ur right... i didnt read 1st line :P anyway ....

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  the problem was string testing AND multiple variables against a value.  primarily string testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second line evaluates to True.  Because the string "no" evaluates to true

try the following

```
if "any string": print(1) #will always print 1, unless the string is empty
```

What you should use instead is

```
while choice not in ["yes", "no"]:
```

which checks if `choice` matches either `"yes"` or `"no"`

Comment: I can't like it because I got no reputation, but I will accept it in a while !

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
while choice != "yes" or "no":
```

This is interpreted by Python as `(choice != "yes") or ("no")`. Since `"no"` is a string of non-zero length, it is truthy. This makes the `or` expression true because anything OR true is true. So your condition is always true and the loop never stops.

It should be:

```
while choice != "yes" and choice != "no":
```

Or:

```
while choice not in ("yes", "no"):
```

Comment: Thank you, for the quick answer ! I appreciate that !